# Prime Number Formula

Tags: c#, math, formula, primes

I am trying to write a prime number function in C# and I am wondering if the follow code will work. It "appears" to work with the first 50 numbers or so. I just want to make sure it will work no matter how big the number is:

```
static bool IsPrime(int number)
{
    if ((number == 2) || (number == 3) || (number == 5) || (number == 7) || (number == 9))
            return true;

    if ((number % 2 != 0) && (number % 3 != 0) && (number % 5 != 0) &&
        (number % 7 != 0) && (number % 9 != 0) && (number % 4 != 0) &&
        (number % 6 != 0))
        return true;

        return false;
 }
```

Comment: Why not just use % 2?  9 is probably [experimental error](http://www.workjoke.com/mathematicians-jokes.html).

Comment: Looking at Your rep, questions and answers - are You playing a joke here? ;)

Comment: Not necessarily, because any prime number greater than 10 would also need to be checked for (ex. 121 = 11 * 11 from the accepted answer).  Also, no need to check for `% 6`, since it is a multiple of `% 2`, and `% 9`, since it is a multiple of `% 3`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No it won't work! Try `121 = 11 * 11` for example which obviously isn't a prime.

For any number given to your function, that is a product of the prime numbers `X1, X2, ..., Xn`(where **n >= 2**) with all of them being greater or equal to 11, your function will return true. (And also, as already said, 9 isn't a prime).

From wikipedia you can see that:

> In mathematics, a prime number (or a prime) is a natural number that has exactly two distinct  natural number divisors: 1  and itself.

so a very simple and naive algorithm on checking whether a number is prime could be:

```
public bool CalcIsPrime(int number) {

    if (number == 1) return false;
    if (number == 2) return true;

    if (number % 2 == 0) return false; // Even number     

    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++) { // Advance from two to include correct calculation for '4'
       if (number % i == 0) return false;
    }

    return true;

}
```

For better algorithms check here: [Primality Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test)

If you want to check your code, do inlcude a **test**, here's a test case written in [xunit](https://xunit.github.io/).

```
        [Theory]
        [MemberData(nameof(PrimeNumberTestData))]
        public void CalcIsPrimeTest(int number, bool expected) {
            Assert.Equal(expected, CalcIsPrime(number));
        }

        public static IEnumerable<object[]> PrimeNumberTestData() {
            yield return new object[] { 0, false };
            yield return new object[] { 1, false };
            yield return new object[] { 2, true };
            yield return new object[] { 3, true };
            yield return new object[] { 4, false };
            yield return new object[] { 5, true };
            yield return new object[] { 6, false };
            yield return new object[] { 7, true };
            yield return new object[] { 8, false };
            yield return new object[] { 9, false };
            yield return new object[] { 10, false };
            yield return new object[] { 11, true };
            yield return new object[] { 23, true };
            yield return new object[] { 31, true };
            yield return new object[] { 571, true };
            yield return new object[] { 853, true };
            yield return new object[] { 854, false };
            yield return new object[] { 997, true };
            yield return new object[] { 999, false };
        }
```

Comment: > "If it was so easy to check if a number was prime then I guess RSA wouldn't be so secure "

Actually, RSA security depends on it being _easy_ to tell if a number is a prime (this makes secure key generation possible), and _hard_ for it to factor the product of two primes (this makes the encryption secure).

Comment: It's only necessary to test up to Math.sqrt(number)

Comment: @Malfist yes I know, it's enough! As I wrote it's a simple and naive algorithm.

Comment: and you can increment i by 2, once it's odd (so from 3) cause all even numbers (other than 2) are not primes

Comment: Replace first two lines with `if ((number&1) == 0) return number == 2; if (number < 9) return number > 1;` to properly handle 1 and negative numbers. And for the love of all that's holy, test only the odds up to the square root!

Comment: WHY are you advancing by one? Start from 3 and advance by 2!!

Comment: I think you may have broke your algorithm when you made it advance by 2, I haven't tested but I think that it would return true for all even numbers > 2

Comment: This returns `true` for all powers of 2.

Comment: This method doesn't work it shouldn't be marked as the answer, it fails for any negative number and any number less than 9.

Answer (score 11):

It had to be done...

```
public static bool IsPrime(this int number)
{
    return (Enumerable.Range(1,number).Where(x => number % x == 0).Count() == 2);
}
```

Comment: return (Enumerable.Range(1, number).Count(x => number % x == 0) == 2);

Comment: Linq is much slower than the method version. I just tested it in milliseconds: 18:162 for true, and 29:1387 for false on numbers 1-10,000. But yeah, gotta at least show how it's done :) I'm not sure why true is faster. The method I am using is virtually identical to the one given in the accepted answer. Anyway, so much for an interesting waste of time. It could be something with the speed it is calculating it. It won't get it if it is less than a millisecond. But the linq is the same way. Interesting.

Comment: Actually, my method code only calculates up to the sqrt. That could make a difference. **And it did.** Once I corrected that, there is little difference. 14:24, and 10:35.

Comment: return Enumerable.Range(1, i / 2).Count(x => i % x == 0) == 1;

Answer (score 3):

This approach definitely won't work, unless your if statement explicitly enumerates all the prime numbers between 0 and sqrt(INT_MAX) (or the C# equivalent).

To properly check for primality, you basically need to attempt to divide your number by every prime number less than its square root.  The [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) algorithm is your best bet.

Comment: int.MaxValue gives the C# max for an int.

Comment: No, you only need to test up to the square root.

Comment: @starblue:  For any particular number, you need to test up to its square root (as I said in my answer).  For a general function to work for ALL possible inputs, it would have to encode all the primes up to the square root of its max possible input.  Obviously if you were really going to write it this way (don't!!!), you'd need it to short circuit.  Probably with a reversed switch statement with fall through if you were doing it in C.  Better just to use an array of some kind though...

Comment: If you extend the approach of the original poster to cover int you need to explicitly list the primes up to sqrt(INT_MAX).

Comment: @starblue:  Exactly what I was trying to say... :)

Comment: @starblue: Oh, whoops--now I see your point.  I said 0 to INT_MAX, but meant 0 to sqrt(INT_MAX).  Editing now...

Answer (score 2):

You are apparently writing from a contrafactual dimension where 9 is a prime number, so I guess that our answers might not work for you. Two things though:

1. Prime number generating functions are a non-trivial but exiting matter, the Wikipedia page is a good starter (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes)
2. from (number%2!=0) it follows (number%4!=0). If you can't divide by 10, then you can't divide by 100 either.

Answer (score 1):

Primality testing is the way to go, but in case you want a quick and dirty hack, here's something.

If it's not working fast enough, you can build a class around it and store the PrimeNumbers collection from call to call, rather than repopulating it for each call.

```
    public bool IsPrime(int val)
    {
        Collection<int> PrimeNumbers = new Collection<int>();
        int CheckNumber = 5;
        bool divisible = true;
        PrimeNumbers.Add(2);
        PrimeNumbers.Add(3);

        // Populating the Prime Number Collection
        while (CheckNumber < val)
        {
            foreach (int i in PrimeNumbers)
            {
                if (CheckNumber % i == 0)
                {
                    divisible = false;
                    break;
                }
                if (i * i > CheckNumber) { break; }
            }
            if (divisible == true) { PrimeNumbers.Add(CheckNumber); }
            else { divisible = true; }
            CheckNumber += 2;
        }
        foreach (int i in PrimeNumbers)
        {
            if (CheckNumber % i == 0)
            {
                divisible = false;
                break;
            }
            if (i * i > CheckNumber) { break; }
        }
        if (divisible == true) { PrimeNumbers.Add(CheckNumber); }
        else { divisible = true; }

        // Use the Prime Number Collection to determine if val is prime
        foreach (int i in PrimeNumbers)
        {
            if (val % i == 0) { return false; }
            if (i * i > val) { return true; }
        }
        // Shouldn't ever get here, but needed to build properly.
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some basic rules you can follow to check if a number is prime

1. Even numbers are out.  If x % 2 = 0, then it is not prime
2. All non-prime numbers have prime factors.  Therefore, you only need test a number against primes to see if it factors
3. The highest possible factor any number has is it's square root.  You only need to check if values <= sqrt(number_to_check) are even divisible.

Using that set of logic, the following formula calculates 1,000,000 Primes Generated in: 134.4164416 secs in C# in a single thread.

```
    public IEnumerable<long> GetPrimes(int numberPrimes)
    {
      List<long> primes = new List<long> { 1, 2, 3 };
      long startTest = 3;

      while (primes.Count() < numberPrimes)
      {
        startTest += 2;
        bool prime = true;
        for (int pos = 2; pos < primes.Count() && primes[pos] <= Math.Sqrt(startTest); pos++)
        {
          if (startTest % primes[pos] == 0)
          {
            prime = false;
          }
        }
        if (prime)
          primes.Add(startTest);
      }
      return primes;
    }
```

Bear in mind, there is lots of room for optimization in the algorithm.  For example, the algorithm could be parallelized.  If you have a prime number (let's say 51), you can test all the numbers up to it's square (2601) for primeness in seperate threads as all it's possible prime factors are stored in the list.

Answer (score 1):

this is a simple one

only odd numbers are prime....so

```
static bool IsPrime(int number)
{
int i;
if(number==2)
    return true;                    //if number is 2 then it will return prime
for(i=3,i<number/2;i=i+2)           //i<number/2 since a number cannot be 
  {                                     //divided by more then its half
    if(number%i==0)                 //if number is divisible by i, then its not a prime
          return false;
  }
return true;                        //the code will only reach here if control
}                                       //is not returned false in the for loop
```

Comment: What is the result of `IsPrime(4)`?

Answer (score 1):

```
    static List<long> PrimeNumbers = new List<long>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PrimeNumbers.Add(2);
        PrimeNumbers.Add(3);
        PrimeNumbers.Add(5);
        PrimeNumbers.Add(7);
        for (long i = 11; i < 10000000; i += 2)
        {
            if (i % 5 != 0)
                if (IsPrime(i))
                    PrimeNumbers.Add(i);
        }
    }

    static bool IsPrime(long number)
    {
        foreach (long i in PrimeNumbers)
        {
            if (i <= Math.Sqrt(number))
            {
                if (number % i == 0)
                    return false;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple code for find prime number depend on your input.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String input = Console.ReadLine();
        long num = Convert.ToInt32(input);
        long a, b, c;
        c = 2;
        for(long i=3; i<=num; i++){
            b = 0;
            for (long j = 2; j < i ; j++) {
                a = i % j;
                if (a != 0) {
                    b = b+1;
                }
                else {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(b == i-2){
                Console.WriteLine("{0}",i);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[ExchangeCore Forums](http://forums.exchangecore.com/topic/895-c-prime-number-generator-console-application/) have a good bit of code that will pretty much let you generate any ulong number for primes.  But basically here's the gist:

```
int primesToFind = 1000;
int[] primes = new int[primesToFind];
int primesFound = 1;
primes[0] = 2;
for(int i = 3; i < int.MaxValue() && primesFound < primesToFind; i++)
{
   bool isPrime = true;
   double sqrt = Math.sqrt(i);
   for(int j = 0; j<primesFound && primes[j] <= sqrt; j++)
   {
      if(i%primes[j] == 0)
      {
         isPrime = false;
         break;
      }
   }
   if(isPrime)
      primes[primesFound++] = i;
}
```

Once this code has finished running your primes will all be found in the primes array variable.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/comp-number-theory/a/trial-division

```
    public static bool isPrime(int number)
    {
        for (int k = 2; k <= Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(number)); k++)
        {
            if (number > k && number % k == 0)
                break;
            if (k >= Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(number)) || number == k)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Prime Numbers from 0 - 1 Million in less than two tenths of a second**

Just finished it. Last test was 0.017 seconds.

*Regular HP Laptop. 2.1 GHz*

It takes longer when it gets larger. For primes **1 - 1 billion** , my last test was 28.6897 seconds. It might be faster in your program because I was casting class objects to get parameter values in mine.

**Method Info**

- Uses the Sieve of Eratosthenes
- Accepts floor and ceiling as arguments
- Uses arrays instead of lists for fast performance
- Size of array is initialized according to Rosser-Schoenfeld upper bound
- Skips multiples of 2, 5, and 7 when assigning values
- Max range is between 0 and 2,147,483,646   *(1 min 44.499 s)*
- Heavily commented

**Using**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections;
```

**Method**

```
private static int[] GetPrimeArray(int floor, int ceiling)
{
    // Validate arguments.
    if (floor > int.MaxValue - 1)
        throw new ArgumentException("Floor is too high. Max: 2,147,483,646");
    else if (ceiling > int.MaxValue - 1)
        throw new ArgumentException("Ceiling is too high. Max: 2,147,483,646");
    else if (floor < 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Floor must be a positive integer.");
    else if (ceiling < 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Ceiling must be a positve integer.");
    else if (ceiling < floor)
        throw new ArgumentException("Ceiling cannot be less than floor.");

    // This region is only useful when testing performance.
    #region Performance

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    #endregion

    // Variables:
    int stoppingPoint = (int)Math.Sqrt(ceiling);
    double rosserBound = (1.25506 * (ceiling + 1)) / Math.Log(ceiling + 1, Math.E);
    int[] primeArray = new int[(int)rosserBound];
    int primeIndex = 0;
    int bitIndex = 4;
    int innerIndex = 3;

    // Handle single digit prime ranges.
    if (ceiling < 11)
    {
        if (floor <= 2 && ceiling >= 2) // Range includes 2.
            primeArray[primeIndex++] = 2;

        if (floor <= 3 && ceiling >= 3) // Range includes 3.
            primeArray[primeIndex++] = 3;

        if (floor <= 5 && ceiling >= 5) // Range includes 5.
            primeArray[primeIndex++] = 5;

        return primeArray;
    }

    // Begin Sieve of Eratosthenes. All values initialized as true.
    BitArray primeBits = new BitArray(ceiling + 1, true); 
    primeBits.Set(0, false); // Zero is not prime.
    primeBits.Set(1, false); // One is not prime.

    checked // Check overflow.
    {
        try
        {
            // Set even numbers, excluding 2, to false.
            for (bitIndex = 4; bitIndex < ceiling; bitIndex += 2)
                primeBits[bitIndex] = false;
        }
        catch { } // Break for() if overflow occurs.
    }

    // Iterate by steps of two in order to skip even values.
    for (bitIndex = 3; bitIndex <= stoppingPoint; bitIndex += 2)
    {
        if (primeBits[bitIndex] == true) // Is prime.
        {
            // First position to unset is always the squared value.
            innerIndex = bitIndex * bitIndex;
            primeBits[innerIndex] = false;

            checked // Check overflow.
            {
                try
                {
                    // Set multiples of i, which are odd, to false.
                    innerIndex += bitIndex + bitIndex;
                    while (innerIndex <= ceiling)
                    {
                        primeBits[innerIndex] = false;
                        innerIndex += bitIndex + bitIndex;
                    }
                }
                catch { continue; } // Break while() if overflow occurs.
            }
        }
    }

    // Set initial array values.
    if (floor <= 2)
    {
        // Range includes 2 - 5.
        primeArray[primeIndex++] = 2;
        primeArray[primeIndex++] = 3;
        primeArray[primeIndex++] = 5;
    }

    else if (floor <= 3)
    {
        // Range includes 3 - 5.
        primeArray[primeIndex++] = 3;
        primeArray[primeIndex++] = 5;
    }
    else if (floor <= 5)
    {
        // Range includes 5.
        primeArray[primeIndex++] = 5;
    }

    // Increment values that skip multiples of 2, 3, and 5.
    int[] increment = { 6, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2 };
    int indexModulus = -1;
    int moduloSkipAmount = (int)Math.Floor((double)(floor / 30));

    // Set bit index to increment range which includes the floor.
    bitIndex = moduloSkipAmount * 30 + 1;

    // Increase bit and increment indicies until the floor is reached.
    for (int i = 0; i < increment.Length; i++)
    {
        if (bitIndex >= floor)
            break; // Floor reached.

        // Increment, skipping multiples of 2, 3, and 5.
        bitIndex += increment[++indexModulus];
    }

    // Initialize values of return array.
    while (bitIndex <= ceiling)
    {
        // Add bit index to prime array, if true.
        if (primeBits[bitIndex])
            primeArray[primeIndex++] = bitIndex;

        checked // Check overflow.
        {
            try
            {
                // Increment. Skip multiples of 2, 3, and 5.
                indexModulus = ++indexModulus % 8;
                bitIndex += increment[indexModulus];
            }
            catch { break; } // Break if overflow occurs.
        }
    }

    // Resize array. Rosser-Schoenfeld upper bound of π(x) is not an equality.
    Array.Resize(ref primeArray, primeIndex);

    // This region is only useful when testing performance.
    #region Performance

    sw.Stop();

    if (primeArray.Length == 0)
        Console.WriteLine("There are no prime numbers between {0} and {1}",
            floor, ceiling);
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
        for (int i = 0; i < primeArray.Length; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("{0,10}:\t\t{1,15:#,###,###,###}", i + 1, primeArray[i]);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Calculation time:\t{0}", sw.Elapsed.ToString());

    #endregion

    return primeArray;
}
```

Comments are welcome! Especially improvements.

Comment: This doesn't really have much to do with the original question.

Comment: @Teepeemm : "I am trying to write a prime number function in C#" The function above is a prime number function. I didn't name it "IsPrime" but it does the same thing. To find out if 951 is prime, use GetPrimeArray(951, 951). It writes "There are no prime numbers between 951 and 951."

Answer (score 0):

Here we must have to consider the square root factor. A prime number can be verified if it is not divisible by any number less than the value of square root of any near number.

```
static bool isPrime(long number) 
{
    if (number == 1) return false;
    if (number == 2) return true;
    if (number % 2 == 0) return false; //Even number     
    long nn= (long) Math.Abs(Math.Sqrt(number));
    for (long i = 3; i < nn; i += 2)  {
       if (number % i == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```