# C# Finding the Nth prime number

Tags: c#, primes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prime Number Formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285562/prime-number-formula)

I am trying to write some code in c# that will give me the nth prime number but once my code gets past 121 as a prime number it starts giving me incorrect numbers back.

Now this could be that i have based my code off the wrong algorithm but i wanted to ask here and see if there is something i have done wrong.

the code ask for nth prime 10001 - output: 43751 (which i know is wrong)

Any where here is my code.

```
int[] p;
int x = 0;
p = new int[10002];
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
if (i % 2 != 0)
{
    if (i % 3 != 0)
    {
        if (i % 5 != 0)
        {
            if (i % 7 != 0)
            {
                p[x] = i;
                x++;
                if (x == 10001)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So if a number is not divisible by 2,3,5 or 7 it's prime? Are you sure about that?

Comment: from what i could work out from wiki - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes - but maybe i misread this and it would works up to 121 : /

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how the Sieve of Eratosthenes works, you should read this section from the Wikipedia article :

> - Create a list of consecutive integers from 2 to n: (2, 3, 4, ..., n).
> - Initially, let p equal 2, the first prime number.
> - Starting from p, count up in increments of p and mark each of these numbers greater than p itself in the list. These numbers will be 2p, 3p, 4p, etc.; note that some of them may have already been marked.
> - Find the first number greater than p in the list that is not marked; let p now equal this number (which is the next prime).
> - If there were no more unmarked numbers in the list, stop. Otherwise, repeat from step 3.

So basically what you think is the limit (`121`, from your comments) is just an example they used in that animated `.gif`.

here's a C# implementation of this method :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace sieve
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int maxprime = int.Parse(args[0]);
            ArrayList primelist = sieve(maxprime);

            foreach (int prime in primelist)
                Console.WriteLine(prime);

            Console.WriteLine("Count = " + primelist.Count);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static ArrayList sieve(int arg_max_prime)
        {
            BitArray al = new BitArray(arg_max_prime, true);

            int lastprime = 1;
            int lastprimeSquare = 1;

            while (lastprimeSquare <= arg_max_prime)
            {
                lastprime++;

                while (!(bool)al[lastprime])
                    lastprime++;

                lastprimeSquare = lastprime * lastprime;

                for (int i = lastprimeSquare; i < arg_max_prime; i += lastprime)
                    if (i > 0)
                        al[i] = false;
            }

            ArrayList sieve_2_return = new ArrayList();

            for (int i = 2; i < arg_max_prime; i++)
                if (al[i])
                    sieve_2_return.Add(i);

            return sieve_2_return;
        }
    }
}
```

Credits go to [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#C.23)

Answer (score 2):

Thats because your algorithm is incredibly broken - you are just testing for numbers that are not divisible by 2, 3, 5 and 7 when you need to test against **all*** primes less than the current number.

Have a quick read of [Fun With Prime Numbers](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/primenumbers/primenumbers.htm) which has some of the more intuitive methods for finding primes, in general though algorithms for finding primes are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

*(*) Actually you can test against fewer primes than this, but my point is that testing against a finite number of primes won't work*

**Update:** Your algorithm isn't [The Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), it just tests against the same numbers that the Sieve would in the case where `n = 120`.  You should have another read of the "Algorithm description" section of that Wikipedia article.

Comment: You don't have to test agains all primes less that the current number. You have to test agains all primes less than or equal to *the square root* of the current number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide that number with all numbers up to the square root of it.

For example you need to divide 100 with sqrt(100) = 10 and if it's not divisable with it then it's a prime number so all you need to do is just

```
for(int i = 2; i <= Math.Sqrt(number); i++)
{
    if(number%i == 0) return false;
}
return true;
```

Comment: Loop must start from 2. This code throws divisionbyzero exception.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that... this was just writen without much thinking...

Answer (score 0):

The below code prints all prime numbers till 1000000

```
        private static void FindPrimeNumber()
        {
            int topNumber = 1000000;
            var numbers = new BitArray(topNumber, true);

            for(int i = 2; i < topNumber; i++)
                if(numbers[i])
                {
                    for(int j = i * 2; j < topNumber; j += i)
                        numbers[j] = false;
                }

            int primes = 0;

            for(int i = 1; i < topNumber; i++)
                if(numbers[i])
                {
                    primes++;
                    Console.Out.WriteLine(i);
                }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Out.WriteLine(primes + " out of " + topNumber + " prime numbers found.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```