# Prime numbers with range up to 10^15

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

How can I optimize the speed/efficiency of my algorithm?

I need to count total of prime numbers in a range from 1 to 10^15.
EDIT: Constraint : `last-first<=10^9`
The below code works for a smaller range (from 1 to 2000000) and it takes 4 seconds (almost).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] s = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        var first = Convert.ToInt64(s[0]);
        var last = Convert.ToInt64(s[1]);
        int counter = 0;
        for (long i = first; i <= last; i++)
        {
            if (i > 2 && i%2==0)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (isPrime(i))
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(counter);
        TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Now - start;
        Console.WriteLine(duration.TotalMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static bool isPrime(long number)
    {
        if (number == 1) return false;
        if (number == 2) return true;

        for (int i = 2; i <= Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(number)); ++i)
        {
            if (number % i == 0) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

As you can see in `for loop`, first I examine whether the number is `i > 2 && i%2==0` since in that case the number isn't prime.

Is there any more tricks to avoid such numbers not to get to the `isPrime` method, or what's the best solution to avoid timeouts?  Notice: this code works but problem is I need to avoid timeout which is 4 seconds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prime Number Formula](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285562/prime-number-formula)

Comment: You can trivially reduce the time a bit by only checking odd numbers for primality.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I did that with i%2==0 in for loop

Comment: @gagro - yes, but *inside* `isPrime` you check `number` modded with *every* `i` when you could easily check only modded with every *odd* `i`.

Comment: If you start on an odd number and increment by 2, you can eliminate that conditional expression. That's what he meant by a trivial reduction.

Comment: https://github.com/kimwalisch/primecount contains a few different algorithms for counting primes that can solve your problem in the 4s time limit. 10^15 is large enough to make simplistic methods way too slow.

Comment: @Nino [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285562/prime-number-formula?noredirect=1&lq=1) .Answers on that link are good but they dont give me any help since I need to avoid timeout.

Comment: @Corak thanks. It makes sense. But anyway  it doesn't avoid timemout. It's faster but not so much on realy big numbers.

Answer (score -1):

To give your `isPrime` logic a head start, you could use something like this:

```
public static class Primes
{
  private static readonly HashSet<int> FirstPrimes 
    = new HashSet<int> 
      { 
        2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 
        67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 
        139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 
        211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 
        281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 
        367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 
        443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 
        523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 
        613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 
        691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 
        787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 
        877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 
        971, 977, 983, 991, 997 
      };
  private const int StartNum = 1009;
  public static bool IsPrime(Int64 num)
  {
    // Check if number is in Prime Array
    if (num < Int32.MaxValue && FirstPrimes.Contains((Int32)num))
    {
      return true;
    }
    // Check divisibility w/Prime Array
    if (FirstPrimes.Any(prime => num % prime == 0))
    {
      return false;
    }
    // Main iteration for Primality check
    var upMargin = (Int64)Math.Sqrt(num) + 1;
    var j = StartNum;
    while (j <= upMargin)
    {
      if (num % j == 0)
      {
        return false;
      }
      j += 2;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

You could fill `FirstPrimes` with even more primes and set `StartNum` to the next prime not in `FirstPrimes`. The more the faster it should theoretically get.

For more primes see for example: https://primes.utm.edu/lists/

Comment: @gagro - of course. As Paul Hankin wrote, any simplistic method would be way *way* too slow to work with primes in the area of 10^15. Even the project he linked to, which is highly optimized and parallelized would probably just barely be able to do the necessary calculations in the given time window of four seconds, let alone display it in a meaningful way (in these regions, `Console.WriteLine` will probably become the bottleneck). So to fulfill your requirements, you need to break out some serious math and code optimizations. And probably collect some awards on the way.

Comment: Btw. I tried an adaptive version of the above code, which stores newly found primes in `FirstPrimes` and sets `StartNum` accordingly. Still not even reached 10^10 in about an hour. Also, storing every prime up to `Int32.MaxValue` would be several GB or even in the TB range. So no way to keep all that in memory either.

Comment: Thank you @Corak. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score -2):

The way I solved this problem is, I sliced the max amount to 5 slices in `SlicerMain` function. `SlicerMain` function further takes lower and upper bounds of each slice and send it to `PrimeCounter` function, which returns total number of primes between the edges of slices.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       DateTime start = DateTime.Now;

       var max = 2000000;// Math.Pow(10, 15);
       int slices = 5;
       SlicerMain(slices, max);

       Console.WriteLine(counter);
       TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Now - start;
       Console.WriteLine(duration.TotalMilliseconds);

       Console.ReadLine();
   }

/// <summary>
/// It slices the big number into smaller ones
/// </summary>
/// <param name="slices">Total Number of slices</param>
/// <param name="max">Big number</param>
public static void SlicerMain(int slices, double max)
    {
       Parallel.For(0, slices,
                    index =>
                         {
                             double up = max * (index + 1) / slices;
                             double low = max * (index) / slices + 1;
                             Interlocked.Add(ref counter, PrimCounter(low, up));
                         });
    }

/// <summary>
/// Optimized Prime Counter
/// </summary>
/// <param name="first">slice lower bound</param>
/// <param name="last">slice uper bound</param>
/// <returns>Count of prime numbers</returns>
public static int PrimCounter(double first, double last)
        {
            int localCounter = 0;
            for (double a = first; a < last; a++)
            {
                bool prime = true;
                for (int c = 2; c * c <= a; c++)
                {
                    if (a % c == 0)
                    {
                        prime = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (prime)
                    localCounter++;
            }
            return localCounter;
        }
```

This `slicing` is used for parallelism and utilization of maximum resources of your machine. Raising slice count will reduce total number of time to count primes but you can raise it up to Cores of your PC or how much parallelism it can afford.
I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I answered specific to the question, for guys like you, let me add some thing more

Comment: You have written the worst possible primality test. From a mathematical point of view you should the division for prime number. It's useless check if the number is divisible for not prime number

Comment: The question is, `Is there any more tricks to avoid such numbers not to get to the isPrime method?` and @gagro is using `i > 2 && i%2==0`, which only filtering out even numbers. So in this range `1 to 10^15`, he is filtering half numbers at least, but he wants (to filter out) more number which are `surely` not prime.

Comment: @Tinwor, please ask question in comments before down vote

Comment: Don't worry, since I'm math I'll never revoke the down vote to your question and I hope that a lot of other people will do the same because your question is simply wrong. It's not a trick do useless calculation. Math is not an opinion, this should be clear.

Comment: @Lali your solution  doesn't speed up the algorithm. I'm talking about up to 10^12-digit numbers.